# Dynamic Paint Ignoring Part of Mesh

Tags: particles, image, collision, dynamic-paint

Trying to make raindrops dripping across the hood of a car. There are particles colliding and sliding along the hood. The particles are a Dynamic Paint Brush and the hood is a canvas.

This is what that looks like (the rain is moving a little fast in the GIF):

[image: setup]

To avoid using a high poly mesh, I'm using an Image sequence instead of vertex data as output.

But, when using Image Sequence, I get this result (this is the wetmap):

[image]

The output lines up perfectly with a line on my mesh (this is the paintmap):

[image]

[image: closeup image]

Here are my canvas settings:

[image]

And the brush settings:

[image]

For reference, here is what happens when I change canvas output type from Image Sequence to Vertex:

[image]

There are no vertex groups, the UVs are clean. Attempted on 2.90.1 and 2.93 alpha.